# Duplicated resource file when uploading jslint.xml to Sonar

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jslint, sonar-runner

I have a Jenkins job which has 2 parts

- Run eslint checks via maven and generate jslint.xml file.
- Upload jslint.xml to sonar using the Jenkins sonarcube plugin.

Our build was working fine until suddenly it starts throwing the exception

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- eslint-maven-plugin:0.1.6:eslint (default) @ gal ---
[ERROR] /mnt/perm_storage/persistent/jenkinssolman_web/jenkins/jobs/com.sap.solman.graphical.component-official_branch_sp1-sonar/workspace/SMGC/src/main/webapp/ags_gal_app/Controllers/extendedEditorEventHandler.js   10:57   strict Missing "use strict" statement. (http://eslint.org/docs/rules/strict)
[ERROR] /mnt/perm_storage/persistent/jenkinssolman_web/jenkins/jobs/com.sap.solman.graphical.component-official_branch_sp1-sonar/workspace/SMGC/src/main/webapp/ags_gal_app/Controllers/extendedEditorEventHandler.js   13:5    no-underscore-dangle Unexpected dangling '_' in '_oExtendedEditor'. (http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-underscore-dangle)
[ERROR] /mnt/perm_storage/persistent/jenkinssolman_web/jenkins/jobs/com.sap.solman.graphical.component-official_branch_sp1-sonar/workspace/SMGC/src/main/webapp/ags_gal_app/Controllers/extendedEditorEventHandler.js   14:5    no-underscore-dangle Unexpected dangling '_' in '_oApplicationToolbar'. (http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-underscore-dangle)
[ERROR] /mnt/perm_storage/persistent/jenkinssolman_web/jenkins/jobs/com.sap.solman.graphical.component-official_branch_sp1-sonar/workspace/SMGC/src/main/webapp/ags_gal_app/Controllers/extendedEditorEventHandler.js   15:5    no-underscore-dangle Unexpected dangling '_' in '_oPaletteToolbar'. (http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-underscore-dangle)
...
...
[ERROR] /mnt/perm_storage/persistent/jenkinssolman_web/jenkins/jobs/com.sap.solman.graphical.component-official_branch_sp1-sonar/workspace/SMGC/src/main/webapp/extensions/vc/solmanDiagramEditorExtension.js    4:0    global-strict Use the function form of "use strict". (http://eslint.org/docs/rules/global-strict)
[ERROR] /mnt/perm_storage/persistent/jenkinssolman_web/jenkins/jobs/com.sap.solman.graphical.component-official_branch_sp1-sonar/workspace/SMGC/src/main/webapp/extensions/vc/constants.js    2:26   strict Missing "use strict" statement. (http://eslint.org/docs/rules/strict)
[ERROR] /mnt/perm_storage/persistent/jenkinssolman_web/jenkins/jobs/com.sap.solman.graphical.component-official_branch_sp1-sonar/workspace/SMGC/src/main/webapp/utilities/globalUtilities.js    6:45   strict Missing "use strict" statement. (http://eslint.org/docs/rules/strict)
[ERROR] /mnt/perm_storage/persistent/jenkinssolman_web/jenkins/jobs/com.sap.solman.graphical.component-official_branch_sp1-sonar/workspace/SMGC/src/main/webapp/utilities/globalUtilities.js   16:5    no-underscore-dangle Unexpected dangling '_' in '_sLocale'. (http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-underscore-dangle)
[ERROR] /mnt/perm_storage/persistent/jenkinssolman_web/jenkins/jobs/com.sap.solman.graphical.component-official_branch_sp1-sonar/workspace/SMGC/src/main/webapp/utilities/globalUtilities.js   23:5    no-underscore-dangle Unexpected dangling '_' in '_oBundle'. (http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-underscore-dangle)

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 46.050s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon May 04 15:35:10 UTC 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/349M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2015-05-04 15:35:11.367:INFO:oejsl.ELContextCleaner:javax.el.BeanELResolver purged
2015-05-04 15:35:11.367:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:stopped o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,[file:/mnt/perm_storage/persistent/jenkinssolman_web/jenkins/jobs/com.sap.solman.graphical.component-official_branch_sp1-sonar/workspace/SMGC/src/, jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/.m2/repository/com/sap/ui5/resource/1.26.1/resource-1.26.1.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/.m2/repository/com/sap/ui5/core/1.26.1/core-1.26.1.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/.m2/repository/com/sap/ui5/commons/1.26.1/commons-1.26.1.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/.m2/repository/com/sap/ui5/layout/1.26.1/layout-1.26.1.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/.m2/repository/com/sap/ui5/unified/1.26.1/unified-1.26.1.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/.m2/repository/com/sap/ui5/ux3/1.26.1/ux3-1.26.1.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/.m2/repository/com/sap/ui5/table/1.26.1/table-1.26.1.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/.m2/repository/com/sap/ui5/visualization/1.26.1/visualization-1.26.1.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/.m2/repository/com/sap/ui5/themelib_sap_ux/1.26.1/themelib_sap_ux-1.26.1.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/.m2/repository/com/sap/ui5/themelib_sap_platinum/1.26.1/themelib_sap_platinum-1.26.1.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/.m2/repository/com/sap/ui5/mobile/1.26.1/mobile-1.26.1.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/.m2/repository/com/sap/ui5/themelib_sap_goldreflection/1.26.1/themelib_sap_goldreflection-1.26.1.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/.m2/repository/com/sap/ui5/themelib_sap_bluecrystal/1.26.1/themelib_sap_bluecrystal-1.26.1.jar!/META-INF/resources/]},file:/mnt/perm_storage/persistent/jenkinssolman_web/jenkins/jobs/com.sap.solman.graphical.component-official_branch_sp1-sonar/workspace/SMGC/src/
[workspace] $ mvn -f /usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/jenkins/jobs/com.sap.solman.graphical.component-official_branch_sp1-sonar/workspace/SMGC/pom.xml -e -B sonar:sonar -Dsonar.surefire.reportsPath=target/jslint.xml -Dsonar.profile=ESLint_Fiori -Dsonar.javascript.jslint.reportPath=target/jslint.xml -Dsonar.profile=ESLint_Fiori -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://ldisonarci.wdf.sap.corp:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8 ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://ldisonarci.wdf.sap.corp:8080/sonar
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building gal 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) @ gal ---
[INFO] SonarQube version: 4.5.1
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/jenkins/jobs/com.sap.solman.graphical.component-official_branch_sp1-sonar/workspace/SMGC/target/sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.5.1
[INFO] [15:35:19.185] Load global referentials...
[INFO] [15:35:19.316] Load global referentials done: 133 ms
[INFO] [15:35:19.334] User cache: /usr/sap/ljs/home/.sonar/cache
[INFO] [15:35:19.348] Install plugins
[INFO] [15:35:19.496] Install JDBC driver
[INFO] [15:35:19.504] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://ldisonarci.wdf.sap.corp:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
[INFO] [15:35:21.177] Initializing Hibernate
[INFO] [15:35:23.421] Load project referentials...
[WARN] [15:35:23.422] Ability to set quality profile from command line using 'sonar.profile' is deprecated and will be dropped in a future SonarQube version. Please configure quality profile used by your project on SonarQube server.
[INFO] [15:35:23.745] Load project referentials done: 324 ms
[INFO] [15:35:23.745] Load project settings
[INFO] [15:35:24.064] Loading technical debt model...
[INFO] [15:35:24.093] Loading technical debt model done: 29 ms
[INFO] [15:35:24.100] Apply project exclusions
[WARN] [15:35:24.101] 'sonar.includedModules' property is deprecated since version 4.3 and should not be used anymore.
[INFO] [15:35:24.424] -------------  Scan gal
[INFO] [15:35:24.429] Load module settings
[INFO] [15:35:26.250] Loading rules...
[INFO] [15:35:26.582] Loading rules done: 332 ms
[INFO] [15:35:26.603] Configure Maven plugins
[INFO] [15:35:26.771] Compare to previous analysis (2015-05-04)
[INFO] [15:35:26.784] Compare over 30 days (2015-04-04, analysis of 2015-04-07 07:45:54.0)
[INFO] [15:35:26.795] Compare to previous version (2015-01-22)
[INFO] [15:35:26.796] No quality gate is configured.
[INFO] [15:35:26.984] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer...
[INFO] [15:35:26.986] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer done: 2 ms
[INFO] [15:35:26.986] Initializer MqrInitializer...
[INFO] [15:35:26.986] Skipping non-aggregator project
[INFO] [15:35:26.986] Initializer MqrInitializer done: 0 ms
[INFO] [15:35:26.986] Base dir: /usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/jenkins/jobs/com.sap.solman.graphical.component-official_branch_sp1-sonar/workspace/SMGC
[INFO] [15:35:26.986] Working dir: /usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/jenkins/jobs/com.sap.solman.graphical.component-official_branch_sp1-sonar/workspace/SMGC/target/sonar
[INFO] [15:35:26.987] Source paths: src/main/webapp, pom.xml
[INFO] [15:35:26.987] Test paths: src/test/java
[INFO] [15:35:26.987] Binary dirs: target/classes
[INFO] [15:35:26.987] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] [15:35:26.987] Index files
[INFO] [15:35:28.386] 414 files indexed
[INFO] [15:35:42.885] Quality profile for java: SAPDefaultProfile_1_3_10
[INFO] [15:35:42.885] Quality profile for js@sap: ESLint_Fiori
[INFO] [15:35:42.885] Quality profile for mqr: ESLint_Fiori
[INFO] [15:35:43.052] Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
[INFO] [15:35:43.414] Java Main Files AST scan...
[INFO] [15:35:43.417] 0 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] [15:35:43.418] Java Main Files AST scan done: 4 ms
[INFO] [15:35:43.418] 0/0 source files analyzed
[INFO] [15:35:43.421] Java bytecode scan...
[INFO] [15:35:43.531] Java bytecode scan done: 110 ms
[INFO] [15:35:43.531] Java Test Files AST scan...
[INFO] [15:35:43.531] 71 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] [15:35:44.546] Java Test Files AST scan done: 1015 ms
[INFO] [15:35:44.546] 71/71 source files analyzed
[INFO] [15:35:44.551] Package design analysis...
[INFO] [15:35:44.565] Package design analysis done: 13 ms
[INFO] [15:35:44.573] Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 1521 ms
[INFO] [15:35:44.574] Sensor QProfileSensor...
[INFO] [15:35:44.577] Sensor QProfileSensor done: 3 ms
[INFO] [15:35:44.577] Sensor CoverageSensor...
[INFO] [15:35:44.577] Sensor CoverageSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [15:35:44.577] Sensor LintSensor...
[INFO] [15:35:44.578] parsing /usr/sap/ljs/persistentfs/jenkins/jobs/com.sap.solman.graphical.component-official_branch_sp1-sonar/workspace/SMGC/target/jslint.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 31.675s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon May 04 15:35:44 UTC 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/320M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project gal: Duplicate source for resource: org.sonar.api.resources.File@60ba6a62[key=src/main/webapp/ags_gal_app/Controllers/extendedEditorEventHandler.js,deprecatedKey=src/main/webapp/ags_gal_app/Controllers/extendedEditorEventHandler.js,path=src/main/webapp/ags_gal_app/Controllers/extendedEditorEventHandler.js,dir=src/main/webapp/ags_gal_app/Controllers,filename=extendedEditorEventHandler.js,language=JavaScript @ SAP] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project gal: Duplicate source for resource: org.sonar.api.resources.File@60ba6a62[key=src/main/webapp/ags_gal_app/Controllers/extendedEditorEventHandler.js,deprecatedKey=src/main/webapp/ags_gal_app/Controllers/extendedEditorEventHandler.js,path=src/main/webapp/ags_gal_app/Controllers/extendedEditorEventHandler.js,dir=src/main/webapp/ags_gal_app/Controllers,filename=extendedEditorEventHandler.js,language=JavaScript @ SAP]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

The error occurs when i try to parse the jslint.xml file.
For this i added the properties "-Dsonar.javascript.jslint.reportPath=target/jslint.xml" in the Addition Properties field in the Jenkins plugin.

If I remove it the jobs will work but the file will not be uploaded.

Any idea what could cause this problem?

Comment: What about your config.xml and Sonar Jenkins configuration ? did you specify yourself the usage of the version 2.6 of the maven plugin for Sonar ?

Comment: no @JeromeVacher i do not know where that come from. it was working ok up until last week. but since monday. i started getting this error.